# In the bottom of my app there is a white space Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  List cardList = [Item1(), Item2(), Item3(), Item4()];

  List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
    List<T> result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
    }
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Card Carousel App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/liberta.jpeg'),
                    width: 120,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Libertà&Ricchezza',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/background.jpeg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    CarouselSlider(
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        height: 240.0,
                        autoPlay: true,
                        autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
                        autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                        autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                        pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: true,
                        aspectRatio: 2.0,
                        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      items: cardList.map((card) {
                        return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: Card(
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                              child: card,
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: map<Widget>(cardList, (index, url) {
                        return Container(
                          width: 10.0,
                          height: 10.0,
                          margin:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: _currentIndex == index
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                          height: 85,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            color: Color(0xff024f9c),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                "L&R PER LA PERSONA",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize:20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                
                              ),
                          ),
                        )),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        
                          Expanded(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/persona');
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                            height: 85,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Color(0xff9c0202),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "L&R PER L'AZIENDA",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize:20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Item1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Item1({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/mandela.jpeg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        onTap: () => launch('https://www.instagram.com/libertaericchezza/'),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            stops: [
              0.3,
              1
            ],
            colors: [
              Color(0xffff4000),
              Color(0xffffcc66),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Item2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:InkWell(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/astronauta.jpeg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        onTap: () => launch('https://www.instagram.com/libertaericchezza/'),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            stops: [
              0.3,
              1
            ],
            colors: [
              Color(0xffff4000),
              Color(0xffffcc66),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Item3({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:InkWell(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/farfalle.jpeg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        onTap: () => launch('https://www.instagram.com/libertaericchezza/'),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            stops: [
              0.3,
              1
            ],
            colors: [
              Color(0xffff4000),
              Color(0xffffcc66),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item4 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Item4({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/car.jpeg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        onTap: () => launch('https://www.instagram.com/libertaericchezza/'),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            stops: [
              0.3,
              1
            ],
            colors: [
              Color(0xffff4000),
              Color(0xffffcc66),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have insert a background image but there is a white space on the bottom and i don-t understand why, i try the resizedToAVoidBottomPadding but doesn-t work,I have insert a background image but there is a white space on the bottom and i don-t understand why, i try the resizedToAVoidBottomPadding but doesn-t workI have insert a background image but there is a white space on the bottom and i don-t understand why, i try the resizedToAVoidBottomPadding but doesn-t work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you try remove bottom safearea, safearea will occupy both top and bottom for notch and control area:

```
SafeArea(
  bottom: false,
```

Comment: No i have found the mistake, the error is SingleScroolView with resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,